# Using pointers and assignment it in C language

Tags: c

What is the output of the following code , i can't understand what is the difference between *x and x , i think that is , are they ?

```
int a = 5 ;
int * xxx  ;
xxx = a;
printf("\n\n%d" , *xxx);
printf("\n\n%d" , xxx);
*xxx = a;
printf("\n\n%d" , *xxx);
printf("\n\n%d" , xxx);
```

Comment: error at xxx=a ... that is the output

Comment: If you can't understand what is the difference between `*x` and `x`, it's better to grab a book and learn C.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `3` and `-3`, or between "symmetric" and "asymmetric"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*x` means your referencing value stored at the address which is held by `x. x` means you are referencing the address which is held by `x.` 
Coming to your code,

```
int a = 5 ; // a contains value 5
int * xxx  ;// xxx is a integer pointer
xxx = a; //  you are assigning 5 to xxx. Leads to undefined behaviour
printf("\n\n%d" , *xxx); //here *x means *xxx? You are printing value stored at address 5 Which leads to undefined behaviour. 
printf("\n\n%d" , xxx); // It will print value 5
*xxx = a; // Here you are assigning 5 to address held by xxx which is 5. Undefined behaviour
printf("\n\n%d" , *xxx); //Printing value stored at the address held by xxx,Leads to undefined behaviour
printf("\n\n%d" , xxx); // printing address held by xxx
```

Comment: xxx = a; //  wrong !
printf("\n\n%d" , *xxx); // undefined behavior

Comment: This answer is wrong as @KaustavRay pointed. Edit your answer.

Comment: he said  "You are printing value stored at address 5 Which leads to undefined behaviour. "

Comment: @haccks I am just explaining what he is doing there and not explaining what happens.

Comment: You might consider editing your answer because still it is not very clear !

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the address of `a` to the pointer `xxx` instead you are passing its value. This code will invoke **undefined behavior**. You will get anything. 
Change

```
xxx = a;
```

to

```
x = &a;
```

Now `x` is the pointer to `a` and when unary operator `*` is used with with pointer then it retrieves the value stored at the address `x` points to. This is called dereferencing.
Also to print the address use `%p` specifier.

```
printf("\n\n%p" , (void *)x);
```